# I'm trying to migrate my ionic cordova project from android 9(pie) to android 13(Tiramisu)

Tags: cordova

after upgrading my android platform to 13 and sdk-tools to 31 or higher versions I'm getting this errror :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/hussain/project/nurture-mobile-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 69
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

## No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher.****your text****

from weeks I'm trying to solve this issue and tried almost every answers stackoverflow and github

Comment: Well did you install them ?

Comment: yes I did install android  platform 13 and sdk tools 33.0.2 and after that I removed plugins and platorms then I did >ionic cordova build android

Comment: <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />  
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33.0.2" />  
    <preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="33.0.2" />     updated my targetSdkVersion too

Comment: but in my Android/Sdk/tools there is no template directory

Comment: I don't think 22 is supported anymore with v13, might be the issue but I could be mistaken

Comment: i made it to 30.0.3 now but yes certainly its not the issue,